# Where is the Salty Oyster?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

> In the bookstore before heading to Comstock there is a recording.

The recording says that some guy's girl has been taken and locked away in some other guy's hidden closet with "treasures" in the Salty Oyster.

Where can I find it?

Comment: If you found an answer, you should put it as an answer.

Comment: Didn't want to answer my own question but ok.

Comment: @Gmoneyrocks [Answering your own question is fine](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never mind I found it:

> Before going through the turnstiles that lead to Comstocks home, you just have to backtrack for a bit. You get the "Return to Sender" vigor, an infusion bottle and there's a recording too. 
> [image]